# where to put the copied live wordpress site in the local (unable to replicate site in localhost)?

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I am new to wordpress, I have to copy a live website to localhost htdocs.I have copied whatever files hosted in TFS VCS and pasted into htdocs folder. Changed wp_ options like site_url and other configs to my localhost.Dumped database from that website into my local mysql and can see it in phpmyadmin. However, when navigate to the localhost directory in this case "localhost/test/src/index.php" it is saying undefined function "get_header()" in index.php.

My question is should I install wordpress locally and copy paste this source into that wordpress installed folder.

Comment: Have you only copied the theme directory?
Properly install Wordpress on your local machine. Copy the content you want from wp-content to your local wp-content directory. Should work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "relevant files"? When I copy from livesite, I copy everything that is inside htdocs.

Comment: I have edited my post..kindly don't downvote

Comment: Do you have wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes inside localhost/test/src/?

Comment: No, actually whatever I copied(htdocs/test/) and the wordpress installation (present inside "htdocs/wordpress" folder are in separate locations. From Thomas Wikman's comment I get that I have to copy files from htdocs/test into htdocs/wordpress/wp-content folder. please confirm.

Comment: Updated an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like you are trying to access theme's index.php directly.

Check [this](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/understanding-the-wordpress-file-and-directory-structure) article or [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-file-and-directory-structure/) one about WordPress File & Directory structure.

**Update 1:**

You mention in the comments that WordPress installation is present inside "htdocs/wordpress" folder. So what is inside "htdocs/test"?

**Update 2:**

If the  "htdocs/test" contains folders like "plugins", "themes", "uploads", then you need to copy the content of "htdocs/test" inside "htdocs/wordpress/wp-content".

And to check if the website work, you go to `htdocs/wordpress/`.

Comment: the code I have from the site is not having the entire wordpress folder structure, it only has as I understand what should be present inside "wp-content" folder the same I did copy into "htdocs/test"

Comment: So inside the "htdocs/test", you have "plugins", "themes", "uploads" folder?

Comment: Updated an answer.

Comment: I have copied them but when I visit localhost now it is blank

Comment: Since it is local environment, try to turn on error reporting. Use this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/turn-on-wordpress-error-reporting/